# Microsoft NLB (Network Load Balancing) and the OSI Layer

Tags: networking, nlb, windows-nlb

I'm unable to track down in the documentation at which layer MS NLB operates at. I'm pretty sure it's unable to interpret Application Layer 7 traffic, for example knowing that HTTP 503 is actually an outage.

In my understanding it sits somewhere on layers 2-4, but I cannot confirm whether a TCP connection reset packet would have it interpret an outage. If it sites at layer 2, I'm half expecting the cluster to interpret the host as offline when the MAC address is non-responsive.

Bonus points: What is the Microsoft NLB heart beat actually doing in the context of the above.

Comment: If layer-2 (MAC) is non-responsive, then every layer above it is also non-responsive.

Comment: OK Thanks. But what if layer 3/4 (e.g. TCP) is non-responsive. How will Microsoft NLB interpret that? Basically I'm trying to get confirmation on whether MS NLB will consider be able to understand that TCP RESET responses are indicative of an unavailable host.